# how to: use $message->render(); in typo3 v 4.5

Tags: typo3, extbase

I need to display a flash message but the message gets gobbled up by another extension, so can I do something like this:

in my controller:

```
$message = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_FlashMessage', 'Valid.', 'Message Header', t3lib_FlashMessage::OK, FALSE );
$message->render();
echo "<br/>".__FUNCTION__.__LINE__."<br/>";  
$this->redirect('validate_success');
```

and have the message show up somewhere on my page, but where, what tag?  Or should I handle the passing of messages differently altogether?

I use typo3 v 4.5.3 extbase 1.3
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it now:

```
$this->redirect('validate_failed', 'Coupon', 'coupons', array('coupon' => $result, 'filename' => $filename, 'message' => 'Expired.'));
```

avoiding the whole flashmessage thing and passing a other stuff I want as well.

and this is my couponcontroller method that catches that redirect:

```
/**
 * action validate
 * @param Tx_Coupons_Domain_Model_Coupon  $coupon
 * @param string $filename
 * @param string $message
 * @return void
 */
public function validate_failedAction(Tx_Coupons_Domain_Model_Coupon $coupon = NULL, $filename = '', $message = '') {
    $this->view->assign('coupon', $coupon);
    $this->view->assign('filename', $filename);
    $this->view->assign('message', $message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you redirect with `$this->redirect()` the `echo` in the same action will never appear.

Correct usage of `FlashMessage` in TYPO3 4.5

In your controller/action:

```
$this->flashMessageContainer->add("Your message body", "Your message header", t3lib_FlashMessage::OK);
```

This will add the FlashMessage to a container which holds all FlashMessages in a global scope.

In your fluid template of the action you redirected to:

```
<f:flashMessages renderMode="div" />
```

Alternatively you can use `renderMode="ul"`.

Comment: And please update to latest 4.5 version. Its 4.5.30 and recommended!

Comment: Hi Merec, That's how I was doing it but it has the problem mentioned and I am using 4.5.3 (but hoping to upgrade to 6.2 next month).  How about that render method, how is it used? Or is it just not used in 4.5?